# Exposing a custom filesystem over SMB or other network protocol

Tags: filesystems, smb

We've written a library that implements a filesystem-like API on top of a custom database system.

We'd like to be able to mount this filesystem as an ordinary filesytem from other machines across a network.

Are there any libraries, that can run in user space, that lets other machines on the network mount this and treat it like an ordinary file system? (Preferably in Python or C++)

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use our Callback File System and expose the filesystem as a virtual disk, which can be shared using regular Windows sharing mechanisms. Callback File System includes a kernel-mode driver, needed to do the job, and offers user-mode C++ API which you use to expose your data as a filesystem.

Once there was .NET implementation of SMB server called WinFUSE, but it's long gone and almost no traces are left.

Update: On linux you can use FUSE to implement a filesystem and mount it, and then use some mechanisms (not necessarily a library) to expose the mounted filesystem as an SMB share.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very interesting option and is close to what we want. Our current servers are Linux based, but we can run a Windows instance for this server.

Comment: @ReamworksSKG I think for Linux custom SMB server libraries must exist. You might want to update your question to specify the desired platform.